# Calculate vacation days between dates

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to get number of days between two dates. There are a number of ways to do it, but I'm not able to find one to suit my purpose to calculate vacation days!

Eg: Cell `A2` dates *21/12/2016* and cell `B2` dates *30/12/2016*.

So the employee is on vacation from Dec 21 to Dec. 30 which is **10 calendar days**, but all the formulas I know show it as **9 days**.

Comment: Aside from the calendar days charging vacation days for weekends, it sounds like your formula is just subtracting incorrectly.  To include Dec 21, you need to start counting from the day before so that the 21st is actually counted.  You need to adjust the subtraction by one day for that.

Answer (score 0):

Dates in Excel are simply serial numbers that start on 1/1/1900.

*21/12/2016* is *42725*

*30/12/2016* is *42734*.

The difference of the two numbers is 9. 
Date difference formulas simply substract the two numbers.

9 is the number of days to get from day 21 to day 30.

One trick is to put in the sheet the **returning day** instead of the last day of vacation. For your example the *returning day* is *31/12/2016*.

Comment: HI, Thank you for the response. That's exactly what I'm doing at the moment. I was wondering if there was any way it could calculate without having to adjust the dates. Glad to know that its the best solution for this. Thank you for your time

Comment: @JoelRodrigues, you aren't really adjusting anything, just counting.  Say you wanted to count the number of numbers from 1 to 10.  You wouldn't subtract 1 from 10 because that would not include all of the numbers you want to count,  Subtracting 1 from 10, 2 would be the first number you count.  If you want to count the 1, you need to subtract 0 from 10.